# SQL - SUM TotalValue returning a null with LEFT JOIN Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'd to like SUM a TotalValue column based on Vendor and logged in user. I completely returning a right value of other info in logged user and the connected vendor, the problem is the SUM of TotalValue column is returning a null value. am I missing something?

This is what I've already tried:

```
SELECT ,v.VendorName ,
        u.Product ,
        v.[Description] ,
        v.Status ,
        SUM(cpm.TotalValue) AS TotalValue
FROM Vendor v
LEFT JOIN [ProductContract] c ON v.VendorId = c.VendorId
AND c.[Status] = 4
AND c.ProductContractId IN
  (SELECT con.ProductContractId
   FROM [ProductContract] con
   INNER JOIN [ProductContractPermission] cp ON cp.ProductContractId = con.ProductContractId
   WHERE cp.UserInfoId = @UserInfoId)
LEFT JOIN ProductContractPaymentMenu cpm ON c.ProductContractId = cpm.ProductContractId
AND c.[Status] = 4
AND c.VendorId = @VendorId
LEFT JOIN VendorContact vc ON v.VendorId = vc.VendorId
AND vc.[Type] = 1
LEFT JOIN UserInfo u ON vc.UserInfoId = u.UserInfoId
WHERE v.VendorId IN
    (SELECT VendorId
     FROM ClientVendor
     WHERE ClientId = @VendorId)
GROUP BY v.VendorName,
         u.Product,
         v.[Description],
         v.Status,
         cpm.TotalValue
ORDER BY v.[Status],
         v.CreatedOn
```

Comment: Hi, i think you can use SUM(ISNULL(cpm.TotalValue,0)) as TotalValue

Because cpm was on Left JOIN and it's can be null in row

Comment: If that particular vendor doesn't have values to sum, what would you expect to see? You are using `LEFT JOIN` so records can be retrieved with null values. If you want to filter aggregates, add a `HAVING` clause.

Comment: Hello @pascalsanchez I tried it now. it returning now a 0(zero) but TotalValue column has a value but still it returning a 0(zero) value.

Comment: @ShibaTatsuya please provided some sample data and current result and excepted result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that you want to apply an aggregate filter, this is the famous `HAVING` clause:

```
...
GROUP BY v.VendorName,
         u.Product,
         v.[Description],
         v.Status,
         cpm.TotalValue
HAVING
    SUM(cpm.TotalValue) > 0
ORDER BY v.[Status],
         v.CreatedOn
```

Comment: The having clause will always result in an empty recordset, because its value is always `NULL` given the current query result.

Comment: @RamondeKlein it will filter vendors without payments, not the ones with and I believe this is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you have to add ISNULL(value,defaultvalue) because cpm table was on left join and it can be null.

```
SELECT v.VendorName ,
        u.Product ,
        v.[Description] ,
        v.Status ,
        SUM(ISNULL(cpm.TotalValue,0)) AS TotalValue
FROM Vendor v
LEFT JOIN [ProductContract] c ON v.VendorId = c.VendorId
AND c.[Status] = 4
AND c.ProductContractId IN
  (SELECT con.ProductContractId
   FROM [ProductContract] con
   INNER JOIN [ProductContractPermission] cp ON cp.ProductContractId = con.ProductContractId
   WHERE cp.UserInfoId = @UserInfoId)
LEFT JOIN ProductContractPaymentMenu cpm ON c.ProductContractId = cpm.ProductContractId
AND c.[Status] = 4
AND c.VendorId = @VendorId
LEFT JOIN VendorContact vc ON v.VendorId = vc.VendorId
AND vc.[Type] = 1
LEFT JOIN UserInfo u ON vc.UserInfoId = u.UserInfoId
WHERE v.VendorId IN
    (SELECT VendorId
     FROM ClientVendor
     WHERE ClientId = @VendorId)
GROUP BY v.VendorName,
         u.Product,
         v.[Description],
         v.Status,
         cpm.TotalValue
ORDER BY v.[Status],
         v.CreatedOn
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Edit: other point you have miss ',' in your query after the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Your left join on `ProductContractPaymentMenu` may not always get an item, so `cpm.TotalValue` can be `NULL` sometimes. When you use `SUM` and when one value is `NULL` then the result will be `NULL`. You might rewrite that part as:

```
SUM(ISNULL(cpm.TotalValue, 0)) AS TotalValue
```

In that case, it will treat non-existing records as value 0.